# Databinding performance issue while loading huge lists

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

i am currently getting despaired of my C# WPF GUI experience.
Im quiet new to WPF and Data-Binding, also im no C# expert...

I tried the demo template for basic MVVM WPF Pattern:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

...and added ~2000 customer to check the gui behaviour on huge data-lists, because i have to deal with huge lists of complex data in my personal project.

Since the display of the Customer-List happens in WPF-Data-Binding-Magic im uncertain how to keep controll of the GUI loading time (which are up to 12 secs with +2000 data).

CustomerRepository:

```
readonly List<Customer> _customers;

/// <summary>
/// Returns a shallow-copied list of all customers in the repository.
/// </summary>
public List<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
   return new List<Customer>(_customers);
}
```

AllCustomerView.xaml/ Listview which contains the customer List:

```
 <ListView 
  AlternationCount="2" 
  DataContext="{StaticResource CustomerGroups}" 
  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CustomerItemStyle}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding}"
  >
  <ListView.GroupStyle>
    <StaticResourceExtension 
      ResourceKey="CustomerGroupStyle" 
      />
  </ListView.GroupStyle>

  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn 
        Header="Name" 
        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" 
        />
      <GridViewColumn 
        Header="E-mail" 
        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Email}" 
        />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Total Sales">
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter 
              Content="{Binding Path=TotalSales}" 
              ContentStringFormat="c"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right"
              />
          </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>



<UserControl.Resources>
<CollectionViewSource
  x:Key="CustomerGroups" 
  Source="{Binding Path=AllCustomers}"
  >
  <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="IsCompany" />
  </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
  <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    <!-- 
    Sort descending by IsCompany so that the 'True' values appear first,
    which means that companies will always be listed before people.
    -->
    <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="IsCompany" Direction="Descending" />
    <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="DisplayName" Direction="Ascending" />
  </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

My Question is:

1. Is there a way i can assync. load the data, without freezing the gui while the list-view is loading?
2. Is there any way i can track the progress, or even get the progress of already displayed data until all items are loaded correctly?
3. Plus: I'm struggeling with the databounding between the GetCustomers() Method and the XAML-Bindings. Where is the "real link' between these two sides?

Comment: Use one way binding,

Answer (score 0):

The following simplified example binds a ListView to a view model with an asynchronous `LoadCustomers` method.

`Customer` instances are created in a separate thread (by `Task.Run()`) and added to an ObservableCollection via a `Dispatcher` invocation (because the collection must only be modified in the UI thread).

The LoadCustomers is executed in the Window's `Loaded` event handler, because it must be `await`ed, which can't be done in the MainWindow constructor.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var viewModel = new ViewModel();
        DataContext = viewModel;

        Loaded += async (s, e) => await viewModel.LoadCustomers();
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; private set; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();

    public async Task LoadCustomers()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
            {
                var customer = new Customer
                {
                    Name = string.Format("Customer {0}", i + 1)
                };

                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Customers.Add(customer));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Well , thanks but since i use MVVM-Pattern i cannot acces to 'Loaded' in the Customer-ViewModel, in fact i cannot access the window in any way.

Comment: @Sweeed you can have loaded method in vm and load that from the constructor itself

Comment: Well, this is MVVM. It isn't *required* that a Loaded event handler calls LoadCustomers (but just an example). You could as well call it wherever you like in your view model.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        ...
        LoadCostumersAsync(); //code after this line executes before LoadCostumersAsync() is finished, so your UI remains responsive
        ...
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Customer> _customers;
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get { return _customers; } }

    private async void LoadStopsAsync()
    {
        IsLoading= true; // you can use this property to show a busyindicator on the UI

        _customers = await LoadCostumers; 

        IsLoading = false;
    }

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ObservableCollection<Customer>> LoadCostumers()
    {
        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            return YourMethodThatGetsCostumers();
        });
    }
}
```